# Creating a directory in Internal memory (Root Folder) Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, directory

I want to create a directory in internal memory (Root Folder), Like the Telegram app that after installing the app that creates a Telegram folder in Root Folder.
I tried this code.

```
   new Directory('dir/subdir').create(recursive: true)
       .then((Directory directory) {
          print(directory.path);
});
```

But I got this error: `Instance of 'Future<Directory>' E/flutter ( 4594): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 'myDir' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)`

I added these permissions in the AndroidManifest. But still not working.

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: should get Storage permission. I'm using the permission_handler plugin.

Second: start direction from sdcard for ex: /sdcard/dir/subdir

```
    final status = await Permission.storage.request();
    if (status == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        print("Allowed");
        Directory newDirectory = await Directory("/sdcard/dir/subdir").create(recursive: true);
    }else{
        print("Denyed");
    }
```